# SQL: Dividing daily data by a monthly index

Tags: sql, postgresql, date

I have daily transaction data that is a product of this query:

```
SELECT  transaction_date  ,
    Merchant,
    Amount

into transaction.table
FROM    source.table
WHERE (DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Criteria%')
```

The field transaction_date is in the format of DATE (yyyy-MM-dd).

What I would like to do is take each row/transaction in transaction.table and divide Amount by a value tied to its RESPECTIVE month (this is key) contained in a separate table called Calendar.

The separate table called Calendar is queried from the same source.table as below:

```
select month,count(*) as distinct_month
into source.Calendar
from
(
select Population, to_char(optimized_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') as month
FROM source.table
group by Population, to_char(optimized_transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')
)
group by month
```

My goal is to get a value for each day: Amount / distinct_month.

The key part is matching the daily data (transaction_date) in the first query with the monthly data in the second query (month).

Note that month from second query is a varchar whereas transact_date in first query is DATE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
SELECT transaction_date, Merchant, Amount, newval
FROM (SELECT transaction_date, Merchant, Amount, Description,
             (Amount / count(distinct population) over (partition by to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM')
             ) as newval
      FROM source.table
     ) t
WHERE DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Criteria%';
```

You only need the subquery because the total is calculated over all the data, without the filter condition.

EDIT:

Oops, I forgot that Postgres doesn't support `COUNT(DISTINCT)` as a window function.  So do:

```
SELECT transaction_date, Merchant, Amount, newval
FROM (SELECT t.*,
             (Amount / SUM( (seqnum = 1)::int) OVER (partition by to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM') )
             ) as newval
      FROM (SELECT t.*,
                   ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY partition by to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'), population ORDER BY population) as seqnum
            FROM source.table t
           ) t
     ) t
WHERE DESCRIPTION iLIKE '%Criteria%';
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried this code and got: "description" does not exist in t."  What did you intend for t?  Any other correction in the code?  Thanks.

Comment: @ZJAY . . . I hadn't noticed that the field used in the `WHERE` clause is not being selected.

Comment: Sorry, I don't follow.  Could you please clarify?  Appreciate your help solving this.

Comment: @ZJAY . . . I fixed the query.  The outermost `WHERE` clause used a column that wasn't selected in the subquery.

Comment: You are amazing, this works!  It takes a very very long time to load this query, however - I don't imagine there is a more efficient way to write.

Comment: @ZJAY . . . An index on `to_char(transaction_date, 'YYYY-MM'), population` might help performance.

Comment: Sorry, one last question.  Say there is a feature for each transaction in source.table called Brand.  And say when I group count(distinct population) by Brand, I get 4 different values, one for each Brand.  Say I want to divide each transaction by the count(distinct population) associated with that transaction's Brand, instead of count(distinct population)  universally.  What would I modify in query?  Thanks!

Comment: @ZJAY . . . I think that is another question.  You should provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126774/discussion-between-zjay-and-gordon-linoff).